# gccgo -static vs -static-libgo

Tags: go, static-linking, gccgo

What is the difference between `-static` and `-static-libgo` for `gccgo`? The documentation doesn't seem to really shed light on what is going on:

- Use the `-static-libgo` option to link statically against the compiled packages.
- Use the `-static` option to do a fully static link (the default for the gc compiler).

Is `-static-libgo` only static linking `libgo.a` only? While `-static` is full glibc library?

Comment: I think -static will try to statically link everything while -static-libgo either only does that with Go packages or only links libgo.a statically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the dynamic linkage in the generated ELFs:

gc builds statically:

```
$ go build hello.go
$ readelf -d hello
There is no dynamic section in this file.
```

gccgo links dynamically against libgo, libc etc. by default:

```
$ go build -compiler gccgo hello.go
$ readelf -d hello
Dynamic section at offset 0x36e0 contains 29 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgo.so.5]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
```

Bake libgo inside the executable, but still link dynamically to libc and friends:

```
$ go build -compiler gccgo -gccgoflags '-static-libgo' hello.go
$ readelf -d hello
Dynamic section at offset 0x128068 contains 28 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

Link everything statically:

```
$ go build -compiler gccgo -gccgoflags '-static' hello.go
$ readelf -d hello
There is no dynamic section in this file.
```